# How to add another background-image to existing background in css

Tags: css

Modern browsers allows to add multiple, comma-separated backgrounds to element. For example I can define 2 backgrounds like this:

```
background: url(image1.png) no-repeat left top, url(image2.png) no-repeat right bottom;
```

It's works wonderfull, and all, but there is often a situation then I want to have one background always applied on element, and another only then I add second class or some modificator. For example I want following code:

```
<style>
    .one { background: url(image1.png) no-repeat left top; }
    .two { background: url(image2.png) no-repeat right bottom;}
</style>

<div class="one two"></div>
```

...to return element with both background applied (code above will return only second).

Is there a way in modern css to add second one without fully copy the first one in it?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with an pseudo-element like after or before and adding a wrap to the element.

```css
.wrap {
    width:500px;
    height: 500px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
.one {  
    width:100%;height:100%;
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/250x250/dfdbb9/dfdbb9.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left top;
}
.two:after {    
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: -1;   
    background-image:  url(http://dummyimage.com/250x250/b9d9df/b9d9df.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;        
    background-position:right bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="one two"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexut/jz0pm47t/1/

Answer (score 2):

@Jason

This code will not work. You have to use this

```css
.one {
  background: url(image1.png) no-repeat left top;
}

.two {
  background: url(image1.png) no-repeat left top, url(image2.png) no-repeat right bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to fully copy anything but I would do something like this

```
.one{ 
    background: url(image1.png) no-repeat left top; 
    }

.two{
    background: url(image1.png) no-repeat left top, 
    url(image2.png) no-repeat right bottom;
}
```

where the second class basically "overwrites" the first class.

The other option is to use a dynamic stylesheet language like LESS ( http://lesscss.org/ ), where you can use variables.

In LESS, you could do something like this

```
@twoBackgrounds: url(image1.png) no-repeat left top;

.one{ 
    @twoBackgrounds;
    }

.two{
    @twoBackgrounds, 
    background: url(image2.png) no-repeat right bottom;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for less idea. If there is no native solution I probably go with it, but I'd still hope that there is a native one. :)

Comment: You have to comma-seperate the background properties, otherwise only the last declaration will be used. The idea of repeating the first is correct though and using LESS variables is an easy way to keep it DRY.